# Android in-app purchase crashing after payment

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have implemented in app purchase in my app I have used "TrivialDrive" example for version 3 of in-app billing, I have tested app by using static responses all works as expected.

But when I download app from market, application crashes on successful purchase,

My code is of successful purchase

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
    if (result.isFailure()) {
    complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
    }

    if (purchase != null) {
    if (purchase.getSku().equals(Constants.IN_APP_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID)) {
        // bought the premium upgrade!
        String message = getResources().getString(R.string.app_purchase_successful_msg);
        mIsPremium = true;
        updateUi(mIsPremium);
        successAlert(message);
    }
    }
}
};
```

I have setting up message on successful purchase but i cant see this message, (means those linse are not executing) when I successfully purchased from it, application crashes after successful payment.

When relaunch app and try to buy item it says already purchased.

I got crash report from developer console.

```
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.eknathkadam.grammaruplite/com.webrich.base.ui.GoogleInAppPurchaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.google.billing.Base64.decode(Base64.java:434)**
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.google.billing.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:87)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.google.billing.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:66)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.google.billing.IabHelper.handleActivityResult(IabHelper.java:437)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at com.webrich.base.ui.GoogleInAppPurchaseActivity.onActivityResult(GoogleInAppPurchaseActivity.java:238)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
02-09 02:01:13.181: E/AndroidRuntime(11530):    ... 11 more
02-09 02:02:20.610: E/JavaBinder(250): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
02-09 02:02:20.638: E/MountService(250): Listener dead
02-09 02:02:20.638: E/MountService(250): Listener dead
02-09 02:02:22.028: E/InputDispatcher(250): channel '41f313f0 com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-09 02:03:59.884: E/PowerManagerService(250): Excessive delay setting brightness: 198ms, mask=2
```

Its throwing Null Pointer Exceptions in onActivityResult() method on this line

```
if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
```

Method is like this

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

// Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
    // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
    // billing...
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
}
}
```

It works perfectly fine on static response but crashes on when I purchase from market.

Comment: We are not testing APK, This bug is reported by user, while he was trying to purchase app, Also our developer come across to same bug when they tried purchasing from market, they have latest version of Google play. Also we were not able to produce same sensoria while testing.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by simply **making my IabHelper member variable(mHelper) static**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same problem. Then, I realised that the entire activity sometimes gets recreated during the purchasing process (by no reason). I haven't tested the Trivia example separately to check if it happens with that app too, but I would expect it, since it seems related to the billing process (or to the helper methods of that example, that I use in my own app too).

The only difference between the billing part of my own code and the Trivia example was that I was instantiating mHelper from a method launched on a certain event, while in Trivia example is instantiated from onCreate. So I made that change (I create new instance of mHelper from onCreate now), and everything started to work fine. The thing is, when the activity is recreated, mHelper gets instantiated again in onCreate, so in the following call to onActivityResult, it can't be null.

Being honest, I have no clue why the activity is recreated and why onActivityResult method of the new instance of the Activity is called, but everything seems to work now.

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds strange, but it works, and it's definetely the source of the problem. I am pretty sure the problem is related to the libraries of the Trivia example, not to the In App Billing itself, so your comment in the original question, "I think in-app v3 is not stable yet", has no sense. I would like @Mac, the person who made the question, to post if he moved the creation of the mHelper instance out of the onCreate method, as I did at first...

Comment: ok and yes,there is some bug,the activity should not recreated.and obviously I had made the comment for in-app v3 (means in-app v3 library),not for whole in-app purchase feature of google.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
What I found was that when the in-app purchase box is displayed, the method onPause is executed in my application activity and when the box is closed then the method onResume is executed.
This is the code of these methods:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
   mWakeLock.release();
   super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Finally I remove the lines in which mWaveLock is executed.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
}
```

and it works fine.
I hope that it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but i probably just had the same problem.
What does your method

```
complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
```

do?

I called

```
Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Premium purchased successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```

in the exact same place, and this caused the following error for me:

```
06-26 14:02:54.229: E/AndroidRuntime(25681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10001, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {sf.com.flightBook/sf.com.flightBook.ui.configuration.ConfigurationMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If this is still relevant for you, you should check your "complain()" method.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I figured out that my public key in my application does not correspond to license key which google play generated for my app